# Retreiving data from MySQL database using Android Volley library is too slow

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-volley

I tried to retrieve a list of form data stored in database in my Android application. Each row of database contains some personal information of a person in string format and also an image of that person. I have stored the images in database in MEDIUMBLOB format.

Whenever I try to retrieve data from my server using JSONObjectrequest of Volley Library in my Android app, the response is usually very slow. Sometimes it takes more than 1 minute to view only 10 to 12 rows retrieved from the database.
This is my logcat:

`D/Volley: [337] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://helpclick.ahsanaasim.me/v1/tasksall/johny 0xa3e020c1 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=14740],`

I tried to search for a perfect solution but I couldn't find anything satisfactory. Here is my Java code:

```
        mRequestStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                showUrl2, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                long totalRequestTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - mRequestStartTime;
                System.out.println(totalRequestTime);
                System.out.println(response.toString());
                try { c1++;

                    System.out.println(c1);
                    JSONArray incidents = response.getJSONArray("incidents");
                    for (int i = 0; i < incidents.length(); i++) {
                        e=0;
                        JSONObject incident = incidents.getJSONObject(i);
                        c1++;
                        id= incident.getString("id");
                        age = incident.getString("age");

                        gender = incident.getString("gender");
                        location = incident.getString("location");
                        //det= incident.getString("det");

                        String image=new String();
                        image = incident.getString("bigimage");

                        if(image.length()!=0) {
                            myBitmap = ConvertToImage(image);
                            Bitmap bitmap= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myBitmap,500,500,true);

                            imgs.add(bitmap);
                            ages.add(age);
                            genders.add(gender);
                            locations.add(location);
                            ids.add(id);
                        }
                    }
                    if(c1>0) {
                        System.out.println(ages.size());
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(search_buttons_page.this, All_Incidents.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.append(error.getMessage());

            }
        });
        jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                20000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

It would be really helpful if someone can tell me the reason of this slow performance and how to solve it by making minimum modifications in my source code.

Comment: What is the range and mean size of the blobs in your database? Are the fetch endpoints slow if you fetch them from a laptop/desktop as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't keep the images in the db.  Keep them in files, and keep the URL of the files in the db.  Download the images separately as needed via URL.  Then you aren't killing your database access times with what should be file IO.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I need a few clarifications. Most experts recommend using filesystem for storing images in db. However, as far as i know,this case will arise when you have thousands of rows in the database. Right now,my database contains only 20-30 rows of data. Why is the process slowing down so considerably even with so litte amount of data to parse?

Comment: Even 20-30 is too much, especially given your Android implementation.  You're storing then 20-30 in memory Bitmap images.  You'll go OOM real quick doing that.  On the server side-  you haven't posted your server code.  Its possible you have other issues there.  But the time needed to send 20-30 images twice (from db to web service, from web service to the client) can be significant.